# C# EF Core unable to change AK alternative key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am having problems with EFCore, precisely when I try to update an entity which has an alternate key and which is also a foreign key on another entity.
I have the following entities:

```
public class IdentityProvider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Scheme { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Properties { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastAccessed { get; set; }
    public bool NonEditable { get; set; }

    public virtual IdentityProviderConfiguration IdentityProviderConfiguration { get; set; }
}

public class IdentityProviderConfiguration
{
    public string Scheme { get; set; }
    public string Options { get; set; }

    public virtual IdentityProvider IdentityProvider { get; set; }
}
```

and these EF Core configuration :

```
public class IdentityProviderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityProvider>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IdentityProvider> entity)
    {
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.Scheme, "AK_IdentityProviders_Scheme")
            .IsUnique();

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.Scheme, "IX_IdentityProviders_Scheme")
            .IsUnique();

        entity.Property(e => e.DisplayName).HasMaxLength(200);

        entity.Property(e => e.Scheme)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(200);

        entity.Property(e => e.Type)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(20);

        entity.HasOne(e => e.IdentityProviderConfiguration)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        entity.ToTable("IdentityProviders");
    }
}

public class IdentityProviderConfigurationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IAM.BackOffice.Core.Entities.AuthZ.IdentityProviderConfiguration>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Core.Entities.AuthZ.IdentityProviderConfiguration> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Scheme);

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.Scheme, "IX_IdentityProviderConfigurations_Scheme")
            .IsUnique();

        entity.Property(e => e.Scheme).HasMaxLength(200);

        entity.HasOne(d => d.IdentityProvider)
            .WithOne(p => p.IdentityProviderConfiguration)
            .HasPrincipalKey<IdentityProvider>(p => p.Scheme)
            .HasForeignKey<Core.Entities.AuthZ.IdentityProviderConfiguration>(d => d.Scheme);

        entity.ToTable("IdentityProviderConfigurations");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to update the schema property on the IdentityProvider entity without it having any IdentityProviderConfiguration children. Unfortunately I always get an error from EFCore like:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The property
> 'IdentityProvider.Scheme' is part of a key and so cannot be modified
> or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity
> with an identifying foreign key, first delete the dependent and invoke
> 'SaveChanges', and then associate the dependent with the new
> principal.    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetPropertyModified(IProperty
> property, Boolean changeState, Boolean isModified, Boolean
> isConceptualNull, Boolean acceptChanges)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectValueChange(InternalEntityEntry
> entry, IProperty property)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.LocalDetectChanges(InternalEntityEntry
> entry)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectChanges(IStateManager
> stateManager)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.TryDetectChanges()    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean
> acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

How can I fix this?  I hope I was clear.
A thousand thanks

Comment: A key is a natural Id and ids are not meant to change. Map it as a property since it appears to be one

Comment: However, by making the query directly on the db, the key is updated correctly.

Comment: The database does not know about natural keys, it's just a unique column. The concept is introduced in the ORM (ef) so it can optimize access because it can assume it does not change just like an id.